# Invalid data found when processing file with ffmpeg API

Tags: android, ffmpeg, decode, aac

I have an m4a file containing two AAC-encoded audio streams. I want to decode it on Android with the ffmpeg library. However, avformat_open_input() fails with "Invalid data found when processing input".

This file was created (i.e. the audio data encoded) with the same library.

I've double-checked the accuracy of the file path I provide to the call.

The file doesn't appear to be corrupt. It plays with QuickTime player, and ffprobe reports the output below.

I've looked at the source in ffmpeg's utils.c but it's not clear at which of several points (including nested calls) this invalidity of the data in the file is being decided.

```
FFPROBE OUTPUT
built with gcc 7.2.0 (crosstool-NG fa8859cb)
configuration: --prefix=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3 --disable-doc --enable- 
shared --extra-cflags='-fPIC -I/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/include' --extra-
cxxflags='=-fPIC' --extra-libs='-L/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib -lz' --enable-
pic --disable-static --disable-gpl --disable-nonfree --disable-openssl --
enable-libvpx --cc=/opt/conda/conda- 
bld/ffmpeg_1530807717919/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc --cxx=/opt/conda/conda-bld/ffmpeg_1530807717919/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ --enable-libopus
    libavutil            55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
    libavcodec         57.107.100 / 57.107.100
    libavformat        57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
    libavdevice        57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
    libavfilter         6.107.100 /    6.107.100
    libswscale            4.    8.100 /    4.    8.100
    libswresample     2.    9.100 /    2.    9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'recording-2019-09-03-110626.m4a':
    Metadata:
        major_brand         : isom
        minor_version     : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
        encoder                 : Lavf58.27.103
    Duration: 00:00:05.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 637 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 314 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
            handler_name        : SoundHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 315 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
            handler_name        : SoundHandler
```

The call that fails with "invalid data found" is:

```
 if ( (ret = avformat_open_input( &inputFormatContext, filePath, 0, 0)) < 0 )
  {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MyTag", "Could not open input file '%s' error %s ", filePath, av_err2str(ret) );
      return false;
  }
```

I would expect this to "just work" since I encoded and muxed the two audio tracks with the same build of the ffmpeg libraries.

When I built the libraries, I configured the build with:

--enable-decoder=aac,pcm_s16le --enable-encoder=aac,pcm_s16le --enable-demuxer=mp4,wav --enable-muxer=mp4,wav --enable-protocol=file,http

When I iterate through the codecs using av_codec_iterate() and look for supported sample rates I see:

```
Found codec aac
supported sample rate 96000
supported sample rate 88200
supported sample rate 64000
supported sample rate 48000
supported sample rate 44100
supported sample rate 32000
supported sample rate 24000
supported sample rate 22050
supported sample rate 16000
supported sample rate 12000
supported sample rate 11025
supported sample rate 8000
supported sample rate 7350
Found codec pcm_s16le
Found codec aac
Found codec pcm_s16le
```

Each codec appears twice, which I thought was maybe the encoder and decoder. But I note that only one has any supported sample rates. My test files' sample rate is 44100.

Any thoughts on what other things I can check for? I wondered whether I should create and pass an AVInputFormat object explicitly to the call, based upon what I know about the contents of the file. But I don't know how to construct one.

Comment: It should work, do you have a sample?

Comment: Sure. This (a couple of random sample tracks recorded in one file using AAC/m4a) was made with the same ffmpeg libraries on Android: https://drive.google.com/open?id=160tXoEvLtH271WZmro4276zHK6frt35Y

Comment: I've just tried avformat_open_input() on a file recorded with the corresponding iOS app, and  avformat_open_input()  fails in the same way

Comment: The file's OK, are you opening it from device storage?

Comment: Yes, it's in a folder under Main Storage. The path is "/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/<file>.m4a". I assume that if that was wrong or there was a permissions issue, the error would have been different, accordingly.

Comment: I've just edited the question to show some new data from iterating through the codecs

Answer (score 6):

In the configure options you must use `--enable-demuxer=mov` instead of `--enable-demuxer=mp4`. The latter doesn't match any demuxer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. This is counter-intuitive: I have --enable-muxer=mp4 and --enable-demuxer=mov for the same format!

Comment: Yeah the `mov` demuxer handles all mov, mp4, m4a ,3gp ,3g2, mj2